# What is the name given to a part of a sentence that's the result of a verb?

Tags: phrases, verbs, nouns

For example, given the sentence:

> Yankee batters hit the ball well enough to win their first World Series since 2000.

What is the name given to the part "*to win their first World Series since 2000*" which is the result of the event "*Yankee batters hit the ball*"?

Comment: It's called a result **adjunct**.

Comment: This is an infinitive clause. The verbs _hit_ and _to win_ are what are called _catenative_ verbs or chain verbs. The complements of these verbs are the NP's _the ball_ and _their first World Series since 2000._

Comment: Note that in 'That's a goal good enough to win the League, the Cup, the Charity Shield, the World Cup, _and_ the Grand National' (Kenneth Wolstenholme) one obviously can't claim a resultative sense. Ignoring hyperbole, such structures do not demand a result ('Elbonton batters hit the ball well enough to win their first Mars Series since 2000, but their fielding let them down').

Comment: It's a complement clause for _enough_, which specifies a level of quantity and can take an infinitive complement to indicate what the level is. In this case, it's measured in results. There's a pretty common infinitive construction with _enough_: _(be) Adj enough to VP_, as in _It's hot enough to fry an egg, He's mad enough to do it, _That's not small enough to carry_. The infinitive doesn't have to be a result, necessarily. And there's no special name given to it; it's just an infinitive clause, syntactically. Semantically, there are a lot of relations possible.

Comment: @BillJ It's not an adjunct though, it's an indirect complement of *enough*, isn't it?

Comment: It would be better to say it's an indirect complement in the AdvP "well enough to win their first World Series since 2000". The head of the AdvP, "well", is  modified by the determinative "enough" which also licenses the infinitival clause.